# Top menu doesnot take the url key values as links

Tags: magento-1.9

I have CMS pages with the url key values as shown
[image]

But in the top menu the

But in the front end top menu the links are not using the url keys.
For example the CMS page "gift registry" has url key "gift_registry". But the menu have link "gift-registry". So the page show 404 error

Answer (score 0):

As per your attachment, Please replace gift-registry with gift_registry then your gift registry page will open properly.currently, you have given wrong URL key in menu.

Comment: This is not working